# Trying to edit a message multiple times with timeout / discord.js

Tags: node.js, settimeout, discord.js

I'm working on a bot and I want to do a message that gets edited multiple times with a timeout function. What I'm trying to do is a loading thing. Here is my code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("message", message => {


        if(message.content.startsWith("$load")){

          const usere = message.mentions.users.first();
          if(usere){


              try{
          message.channel.send(`Loading.`)
          .then(message => {     setTimeout(function() { message.edit(`Loading..`) }, 10000)})
          .then(message => {     setTimeout(function() {  message.edit(`Loading...`) }, 10000)})
              }catch(e){
            }
        }
    }
})

bot.login('Token');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get `promise` message of set `timeout` function, and it will return undefined, you need use something like this:

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("$load")) {
        const usere = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (usere) {
            message.channel.send(`Loading.`)
                .then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        msg.edit(`Loading..`)
                    }, 10000);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        msg.edit(`Loading...`)
                    }, 12000)
                })
        }
    }
})

bot.login('Token');
```

Or you can use interval, for edit every 10 seconds, just set `Loading...` as variable and change it after every call.

```
bot.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("$load")) {
        const usere = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (usere) {
            message.channel.send(`Loading.`)
                .then(msg => {
                    setInterval(function() {
                        msg.edit(`Loading..`)
                    }, 10000);
                })
        }
    }
})
```